# PHP: How do I send variables to the current page?

Tags: php

Sorry for the terrible title; I was unsure how to word this properly.

Basically I have a button, and when it's pressed, it calls a function at the top of the page.

How do I send variables such as ($id, $name, $time, etc.) to the function above when the button is pressed?

Example:
if(button is pressed) -> function();

Comment: Call `JavaScript` function or `PHP` function?

Comment: share your code then ask the question.

Comment: My code is a mess because I am trying to figure how I need to do this. The code is a php function included in another file.

Comment: Is this function to be executed on the server?

Comment: The function will execute a SQL statement. But I don't know how to send all of the variables needed with the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a submit button then add a code before you function `if(isset($_GET['id'])) { // run you function }`

Comment: I don't want to use the $_GET because anyone can add the ID... the only people able to do this function are users with a certain permission. Is there any way to use $_GET and ensure that a user has the appropriate permission to?

Comment: That would have to be part of you function to determine if they have permission and you did not share any additional information so the best i can do is guess
`if(isset($_GET['id'])) { // check if permitted then run you function }else{you get the idea}`

Comment: Basically, this is what I did: https://gyazo.com/fb2a81d7bfdac37ff281f4c3de6de083 and: https://gyazo.com/d00fb035ee4235369872bea384623f33 ... WORKED great!

Comment: @AustinM-S You can never trust data originated from the user, you have to validate everything, always validate everything. You can hide the information on the call by using a `POST` request instead of a `GET` one, but this still won't prevent an ill-intentioned user from manipulating the data relayed to your script.

Comment: @AustinM-S Oh but he does have a way to, it's just not as intuitive. Anyway, to use post, simply use a form with the attribute `method=post`, and include the data as named fields, the named fields may be invisible, by using `<input type=hidden name=variable value=value>` and then submit either by using a button like `<input type=submit value="Click me">` or any clickable element that calls `.submit()` on the form, but that requires a bit of JavaScript.

Comment: I did get it. Thanks! The POST is the better method.

Comment: @AustinM-S I believe you need to use a `echo` there,  `<?php echo $civID; ?>`. Also, notice the object `<form>` has some sort of margin in it by default, you may want to CSS that out to not ruin your formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do your task:

1. You can use a post form and a submit button then just submit a form to send the variable.

   `<form action="" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="idvale" />
     <input type="hidden" name="name" value="idname" />
     <input type="hidden" name="time" value="idtime" />
    </form>`

   Then get the value from PHP function: $_POST['id'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['time']
2. Or you can add the variable to the URL then use GET method from PHP function:

   `<a href="/?id=idvalue&name=namevalue&time=timevalue"><button>click me</button></a>`

But this method is not security.

These are the basic ways or you can use the javascript to do this task instead. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If your function is to be executed on the server.
Then supposing your button is of type 'submit', you can pass your parameters in the post form. Then you can get them using something like:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
```

In that case, you would send something like that from the client:

```
<form action="yourPage.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="id" value="DS-YourID-324-Whatever" />
  <input type="text" name="name" value="your-name" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Button">
</form>
```

I hope this can be of some help.

Comment: The variables are already defined from something else. Which is why I am slightly confused because there are no actual inputs.

Comment: If they are already defined then you do not need : <input type="text" name="id" value="DS-YourID-324-Whatever" /> Use :<input type="hidden" name="id" value="DS-YourID-324-Whatever" />. And write what is needed to have the appropriate content inside you form.

Comment: So like this? https://gyazo.com/56711887461fdd7d7062d28e0184e247 and then I can just use the $_POST to get those variables like above?

Comment: Yes something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is so unclear I'll cover the basics.

You can't have a button in HTML that triggers a function in PHP directly. This is not how PHP works, PHP scripts are not an ongoing application that you can interact with. When a PHP page is called the script will run, generate output, and exit.

In order to interact with user input, aka, receive variables from the user, you have to call the PHP script that will handle the user input with the data in the HTTP call itself.

This can be done several ways and can be handled by the script that generated the page too, no problem there. The typical way of doing it is by using `<form>`.

You can also do something very simple with just a link, by doing `<a href="script.php?variable=value">Click</a>`, the script `script.php` will be called and the superglobal `$_GET['variable']` will carry the value `value`. You can do a lot with that already. Just remember to check if it `isset()` before using it.

A `<form>` may contain text fields, hidden fields, check boxes and all that stuff you typically see when, well, when you fill a form. And when you submit the form, the data in those fields will be sent to the script via `GET` or `POST` methods, depending on what you specify in `<form method=get>` or `<form method=post>`, and the PHP script will be able to handle this information by reading the superglobals `$_GET` or `$_POST` respectively, or `$_REQUEST` which is a mix of both, plus `$_FILES` if the form is about sending a file.

`<form>` also allows you to specify what script (not function) will handle the call, by using the property `action`, as in `<form action=script.php>`.

I won't give you examples on how to use a `<form>`, I'm sure you can find a lot of them on Google.

You can make something more interactive and optimized with AJAX, which is a method of trading data with the server without having to reload the entire page, but that's a whole lot more complicated beast that requires interaction between PHP and JavaScript. Get familiar with the basics before jumping into that.